# Using rs.next() to retrieve data from a specified row

Tags: java, ojdbc

Can I use rs.next() to retrieve data stored at any row I want? To be more precise,I know that rs.next() will run through all the rows and extract the data.But suppose I want the data, for instance name and roll number stored at row 10. Is there any possible way to achieve this? The total row count is 30,for instance

OK what I am trying to do is this:

```
while(rs.next())
{
Blob b=rs.get blob("imagename");

byte barr[]=new byte(3,(int)      

b.length());//create an array to store
data from blob

Image  
IMG=jpane.getToolKit.default      
tool kit.drawImage(barr);
//jpane is the  frame on which I want to draw    the image

ImageIcon icon=new   

ImageIcon(IMG);

JLabel label=new JLabel(icon);
//passing generated icon to label

 label.revalidate();

 label.repaint();

Jpane.add(label);//adding label to    my     frame

 Jpane.repaint();

Jpane.revalidate();
    }
```

What this does is only paint the image at first row.So how can I paint the image  present at any given index?

Comment: Generally, if you need only a small number of rows out of the result, it's better to limit in the query itself than to produce a large result set and then move the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Try [ResultSet.absolute(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#absolute%28int%29):

```
rs.absolute(10);// moves the cursor to the 10th row of rs
```

Comment: :) I think I can put that to use..Thanks arvind

Comment: @user4678940: not every DBMS and JDBC driver supports this though.

Comment: Hmm...yeah that might be true considering I have faced problems like "abstract method error" despite my code being completely functional :)

Comment: @user4678940: Have  you tried to add somethingy on these lines, as told by this function ( [Connection.prepareStatement( "dbmsStatement", ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement-java.lang.String-int-int-), before actually executing the line, as told in the answer.

Comment: Nopes..I haven't..what does it do,if I may ask?

Answer (score 0):

If you need only of the 10th row, why don't you changes your query to return only the specific record?

Comment: I actually want to extract a blob data attached to a varchar data.bit it only gives the result of the first row (see code).